# Getting the event body attributes in Ruby with AWS Lambda

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk-ruby

So I'm new to ruby and I have a simple REST API.

The post request looks like this:

```
POST /endpoint, { 'message': 1 }
```

My lambda handler looks like this:

```
def run(event:, context:)
    puts "#{event['body']}"
    # prints the request body
end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to store `message`, which is an `int` in a variable.

I was trying to do something like this but doesn't work

```
my_int = event['body']['message']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`event['body']` is going to return a string, a json string.

You need to parse it with something like this.

```
body = JSON.parse(event['body'])
my_int = body['message']
```

Also if you were to do.

```
puts event.inspect
```

instead of

```
puts "#{event['body']}"
```

you would have been able to see that body returned a string and not an object. I hope that helps and good luck.